# Installing an android widget from Inside another app

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service

I have a fully functioning Android widget that consists of a service provider class, the receiver class, and some other resources.

I have a separate app that I've successfully imported the classes and required resources for the widget into.  There is a button menu (coded to the hard menu button) inside the app and I want to use a button in it to install the widget.  I don't care if the widget shows on the home page (I know you can't do that from inside an app) I just want the widget to install and become an option on the "widgets" menu from the home screen.
I've tried starting the service from inside the app, I tried sending an update to the widget so it would call .OnEnabled, I tried instantiating the java classes... I'm obviously missing something and can't figure it out from the android docs.

I know this is a really dumb question...

How can I get the serviceProvider to run and install the widget?
(Use WidgetServiceProvider.java and WidgetReceiver.java as examples)

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {        
         ...
    case R.id.installWidget: 
        ????????    
        break;
    }
```

Comment: You should probably post your AndroidManifest.xml and relevant `android.appwidget.provider` XML meta-data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a button menu (coded to the hard menu button) inside the app and I want to use a button in it to install the widget.  I don't care if the widget shows on the home page (I know you can't do that from inside an app)

These sentences don't really make sense to me. You say you want to use an app to put a widget on the homepage.. but then say you know you can't do that from inside an app..

If you're asking about how to get the widget to automatically get installed in the widget menu that is achieved through the manifest xml file.

For a full tutorial you can look [here](http://nexsoftware.net/wp/2009/07/29/tutorial-creating-a-custom-analogclock-widget/), but specific to your question you should only need to add a variant of these tags to your Application tag in your manifest xml file.

```
<receiver android:name="[Package name]" android:label="[Your Label]">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget" />
</receiver>
```

Links for tags:

- [Reciever Tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html)
- [Action Tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/action-element.html)
- [Meta Data Tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html)

Comment: You aren't reading it carefully because I don't contradict myself.  
My widget is not "automatically installing from the manifest."  

I clearly distinguished that I wasn't trying to place the widget on the homepage but just get it installed.  This is not helpful and doesn't include any manifest elements that trigger this "automagic installation"

Comment: I updated my answer with more information based on your comment but if you already have this information in your manifest file then you need to post that file so that we can debug it.

Comment: Your edited answer is more helpful to people referencing this in the future.

My actual problem was that I had my receiver and service tags INSIDE an activity tag.  In the manifest make sure that your activities, receiver, and service classes are are all discrete(with their own intent-filters) in the manifest and that none of them are nested in anything except the <application> tag.

I will mark this as the answer because it pointed me to how widgets get installed through the manifest and because you took the time to edit with more specifics.